# Paramiko in Apache : DLL load failed

Tags: apache, paramiko

I have a Django app that uses Paramiko to communicate with other remote servers.
Paramiko relies on module `winrandom`, but that won't install on windows without `gcc`, so instead I use `winrandom-ctypes`.

This all works fine from development, but when I deploy to Apache (also on Windows), it fails on `import winrandom`, with this error:

```
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So...how can I make this work under Apache?

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem with pyCrypton 2.3. Switching back to 2.1 seems to fix it.